# Make exp() handle large negative values, Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I write code in `Rcpp` and I face the following problem

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
    
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double EXP(double x){
  return exp(x);
}
```

I would like to ask if there is a way to make it for the function `EXP` to handle large negative values. For example, when I run

```
EXP(-5000)
[1] 0
```

Ideally, I would like to have something that is non-zero but extremely close to zero. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `EXP(-5000)` is `3.369870547951800096615642407437e-2172` which is outside the range of `double` (e-308) but not `long double` (if 80 or 128 bit doubles are supported) see __Range of values__ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: Also _"...For IEEE-compatible type double, overflow is guaranteed if 709.8 < arg, and underflow is guaranteed if __arg < -708.4__..."_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp so just test for `0` and return a small number.

Comment: @RichardCritten The issue is of course that R doesn't have long doubles.

Comment: The common approach to this issue is to try and avoid the exponentiation and work on the logarithmic scale.